# SMS not depleting or opening Huawei Y6

Tags: sms, mms

I know this question has been asked here before, but there hasn't been a solution besides to factory-reset the phone.

My phone recently reviewed a SMS/MMS with a title 'No Subject' from a number not on my contacts.

The problem is I cannot open or delete the message. Is there any thing I can do to get rid of this message. My phone is a Huawei Y6 2018

Thnx in advance

Comment: Wow, miraculously this went away by its self after days of looking for a solution. In case anyone has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that your current messaging app is not the default messaging app of the system, thus making messages cannot be removed. Check the default message app in the Settings, and head to the desired messaging app to see if it could be deleted.

You may also consider install the official Android messaging app from Play Store and perform deletions there.